# How do I declare a writable array of constant objects in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, oop, object, constants

I need to be able to set the objects in the array, but I don't want to be able to change the state of any of the individual objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, I'm afraid. There's no equivalent of the flexible "const" from C++ in C#.

If it's your own type, you could try to make it immutable (like `string`) to start with though. That would be pretty effective against changes :)

Note that although your question asks for a writable array, there's actually no other kind - you can't create an array which is read-only when initially populated... you have to use some other approach (e.g. creating a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` wrapping another collection which is *only* known to the wrapper). I know this isn't a problem in your particular case, but I just thought I'd point it out. If you make the variable referring to the array `readonly`, that only prevents other code from setting the value of the variable to a reference to another array - it doesn't prevent changes within the array itself.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can declare a private variable and then declare a property referencing the variable with only getter defined, that sort of makes it read only.

Example:

```
private int[] myArray =new int[5];
public int[] MyArray
{
  get { return MyArray; }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe that addresses the point the OP was trying to achieve - e.g. having an array of type `StringBuilder[]` but preventing the contents of each `StringBuilder` from changing.

Comment: @Jon: hmm..reading his wording again, i guess you are right but i guess the OP should make the decision on what the point he was trying to achieve and down vote my answer and not you..haha...

Comment: I'd actually already undone my downvote, but it seems to be pretty clear that your answer doesn't address the OP's concern.

Comment: @Jon: I agree, your answer i think covers what he's asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using some form of Immutable collection as a better design concept.

Options include returning as IEnumerable, IEnumerable using yield[1], ReadOnlyCollection... See link down below for better explanation.

[1]

```
public IEnumerable<string> Hosts 
      { 
            get     
             {     
                 foreach (var host in _hosts)
                 {    
                     yield return host;
                 }    
             }
     }
```

See http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/11/04/c.net-fundamentals-returning-an-immutable-collection.aspx